# Handlebars JS get the subarray item using variable

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, handlebars.net

I have json with an array of objects which each object has its own sub array.

I want to grab the values from _History sub array using the value in _Year variable I pass into Handlebars js. I can get it to work if I set the value directly into the code ex: `{{_History.[2018].Testa}}`.

Is it possible to set the value of _Year and have handlebars get the right sub array?

The parameter values I pass to handlebars js.

```
    var params = {
        _Person: "THE JSON",
        _Year: "2018"
    };
```

JSON Code:

```
        [
            {
            "_History": {
                "2017": {
                "Testa": "Test 1",
                "Testb": "Test 2"
                },
                "2018": {
                "Testa": "Test 3",
                "Testb": "Test 4"
                }
            },
            "FirstName": "John",
            "LastName": "Doe"
            },
            {
            "_History": {
                "2017": {
                "Testa": "Test 5",
                "Testb": "Test 6"
                },
                "2018": {
                "Testa": "Test 7",
                "Testb": "Test 8"
                }
            },
            "FirstName": "Susan",
            "LastName": "Doe"
            }
        ]
```

Handlebars JS template:

```
        {{#each _Person}}
        <tr>
            <td nowrap>{{FirstName}}</td>
            <td nowrap>{{LastName}}</td>
            <td nowrap>{{_History.[2018].Testa}}</td>      <-- Works
            <td nowrap>{{_History.[../_Year].Testa}}</td>  <-- Doesn't Work
            <td nowrap>{{_History.[../@_Year].Testa}}</td> <-- Doesn't Work
            <td nowrap>{{_History.[@../_Year].Testa}}</td> <-- Doesn't Work
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you want to perform a dynamic lookup you will need to use the [lookup helper](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#lookup) specifically built for that.

> The lookup helper allows for dynamic parameter resolution using
>   Handlebars variables. This is useful for resolving values for array
>   indexes.

```
{{lookup _History ../_Year}} //Object
```

After the dynamic lookup you will need to perform another one to access `'Testa'` or `'Testb'`

You can use a [subexpression](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html#subexpressions) for this:

```
<td nowrap>{{lookup (lookup _History ../_Year) 'Testa'}}</td>
```

If you don't like using subexpressions or need a much deeper lookup I made a custom helper that it's a little easier to use:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('coolerLookup', function(){
   var args = [].slice.call(arguments);

   var block = args.pop();
   var object = args.shift();

   var value = args.reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a[b];
   }, object);

   return value;
});
```

Now you can do:

```
<td nowrap>{{coolerLookup _History ../_Year 'Testa'}}</td>
<td nowrap>{{coolerLookup _History ../_Year 'deep' 'deeper' 'property'}}</td>
```

---

**Working demo:**

```js
var data = {
 "_Person": [{
  "_History": {
   "2017": {
    "Testa": "Test 1",
    "Testb": "Test 2"
   },
   "2018": {
    "Testa": "Test 3",
    "Testb": "Test 4"
   }
  },
  "FirstName": "John",
  "LastName": "Doe"
 }, {
  "_History": {
   "2017": {
    "Testa": "Test 5",
    "Testb": "Test 6"
   },
   "2018": {
    "Testa": "Test 7",
    "Testb": "Test 8"
   }
  },
  "FirstName": "Susan",
  "LastName": "Doe"
 }],
 "_Year": "2018"
};

Handlebars.registerHelper('coolerLookup', function(){
   var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
   
   var block = args.pop();
   var object = args.shift();
      
   var value = args.reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a[b];
   }, object);
   
   return value;
});

var source   = $("#template").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

$("#output").html(template(data));
```

```css
td {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://builds.handlebarsjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/handlebars-v4.0.5.js"></script>

<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {{#each _Person}}
        <tr>
            <td nowrap>{{FirstName}}</td>
            <td nowrap>{{LastName}}</td>
            <td nowrap>{{lookup (lookup _History ../_Year) 'Testa'}}</td>  <-- It Works now-->
            <td nowrap>{{lookup (lookup _History ../_Year) 'Testb'}}</td>  <-- It Works now-->
            <td nowrap>{{coolerLookup _History ../_Year 'Testa'}}</td> <!-- deal with it -->
        </tr>
  {{/each}}
</script>

<div id="output"></div>
```